# How to add Bson ObjectId to JObject

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying return key value by using JObject. I am getting the ObjcetId after insert the value in mongodb. I am using JObject to return the value as key value pair. By using the bellow code i assing the objectid to the key.

`JObject returnId= new JObject();
 dynamic id = Document["_id"].AsObjectId;
 returnValue = returnId.Add("_id",id);`

I am getting **unhandle exception** in the third line. Why i am getting this is issue and how can i solve it.

i want return the value like bellow

`"_id":"12345667889"`

can any one try to help me.

Thank you...

Comment: What's the type and message of your exception?

Comment: this is the message i am getting in catch block "   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , JObject , String , Object )\n   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute3[T0,T1,T2,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2)\n

Answer (score 0):

I change the bellow code

`JObject returnId= new JObject();`
to
`BsonDocument returnId = new BsonDocument()`

Now its working fine.